# Create server for android application

Tags: android, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating an Android application in Xamarin and I want the user to be able to log in with a mail and associate this mail to a server to upload and download content.
For example: I log in with my mail, the application will automatically bring my contents and it will put them in the application. If I create a new file, it will be automatically uploaded to the server.
I don't know if it's clear, if it is not ask me.
I really don't know how to do it, I heard something about SQL, but I didn't understand very well what it is.

Is it possible to do it easily and for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has developped an API named Firebase which allows to have realtime database and a login with mail and password. It's the easiest way i have found.

There is a [tuto](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) that shows how to create a chat app with this api (with mail and google login but you can just use mail login).

It's free untill an amount of 1 GB stored in your database.(just go see in pricing tab)

You can also develop a client-server architecture with e-mail login but you have to manage the security and the management of your database, etc. so it's more complicated. OR, you can use other API like [Quickblogs](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android) .

Comment: You have some libraries for that in Xamarin also named firebase. Just look at this [tuto] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFrXsce431U) .